# Can Ubuntu install alongside on Win XP computer?

Tags: windows-xp

Can Ubuntu install alongside on Win XP computer?  My XP computer crushed after trying to install Ubuntu.  The installer say that it cannot find HDD and installation stops.  It cannot install Ubuntu or Win XP.

Comment: Yes, you can install Ubuntu alongside XP. I suspect there is some problem with your HDD.

Comment: It seems you rather have hardware (HDD) problem

Answer (score -1):

Yes. First install XP in your system from starting. Format Primary drive and install it. Insert ubuntu CD or USB and install it in another partition of HDD.

Comment: How is it possible to do partition and formatting when HDD is not recognized?